# Date is returned incorrectly from excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, date, c#-4.0

I have a Excel sheet with some data. In it I have a date column. When I read the Excel sheet for the date column, it returns a incorrect date (date format month/day/year).

The following is an example of a date value in the Excel sheet

```
01/01/2014
```

and that date value read from C#:

```
1/1/2014
```

But it correctly parsed the date `05/24/2015`.

So when I `TryParseExact` it for a valid date, it always returns false. Is there any good solution to overcome this issue?

Update:

```
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(row["ColoumnNo"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date)) <br>
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: The underlying DateTime value of 01/01/2014 is the same as 1/1/2014; seems its just a matter of the format. Best regards,

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact(row["ColoumnNo"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out data);
I have given like this @AlexBell. But it returns false for the above date.

Comment: If you are specifying the *mm/dd/yyyy* INPUT mask but supplying input in the form of *m/d/yyyy* it seems to make sense that it would fail.

Comment: @Jeeped: In the excel sheet it has in the format of 01/01/2014 but when it read that value it returns 1/1/2014.

Comment: Could you please post a complete code snippet that is causing a problem? It's hard to discuss something invisible. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Why you are using logical negation in if statement !DateTime.TryParseExact (that ! )?

Comment: Can't speak definitively about C# but in VBA the `<cell>.Value` would be *1/1/2014* but the `<cell>.Text` would be the formatted *01/01/2014*.

Comment: "In the Excel sheet it has in the format of 01/01/2014" - I'm guessing that in the Excel sheet the date is stored as a date-type, so internally it doesn't have any format, just a value. What it looks like when you view it in Excel depends on various factors like what the PC's default locale is. In fact, different people will see the date formatted differently by Excel on different PCs.

Comment: I should clarify my last comment. The value returned by VBA would be *1/1/2014* but the underlying value would be *41,640* (i.e. the number of days since Dec 31, 1899). VBA translates the `IsDate` property. Perhaps C# is simply returning the native value of the cell.

Comment: Most likely that provider already returned DateTime, you make string from it and then parse again. You can just accept the value as is.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at your excel sheet you see the following format: MM/dd/yyyy. Your date is just displayed in that format by the formatter in excel. Under the hood it is a date type. When you read the date as a string in c# you get the following format from your date type M/d/yyyy. So you have to change the mask of your TryParse to: "M/d/yyyy". You can better read the value as a date from the excel sheet directly, if you change your culture you will read an other date format from your excelsheet.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted by some others, you'd be far better avoiding the issue altogether by trusting in Excel to tell  you whether there's a date or not.  `Range.Value` is of type `object` and will return a `DateTime`if Excel recognises the contents as a date.  So your code could be written as:

```
var value = row[".."].Value;

if (value is DateTime)
{
    var date = (DateTime)value;
    //code
}
```